# python equation calculation with exp() function

Tags: python, math, equation, exp

Here is the equation I'm tryin' to solve:

[image: original]

the correct answer most be **0.347** and this is what I got:

```
from math import *

exp(((-4.4 + 0.6*(0.6/1.2))*tan(25)) + ((3.07*sin(25))*(log(2*4.29))/(1+sin(25))))
```

output:

```
0.6318
```

I tried to use radians : **tan(radians(25))**
I keep getting wrong results

Comment: How do you know that the correct answer is actually 0.347?

Comment: `log` is the natural log. `log10` is the base10-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.347` (ignoring the rounding error) is correct if you use the base 10 logarithm and your arguments are in degrees for the trigonometry functions.
`0.6318` is correct for natural logarithm and radians.

```py
>>> from math import exp, log, sin, tan, radians
>>> exp(((-4.4 + 0.6*(0.6/1.2))*tan(radians(25))) + ((3.07*sin(radians(25)))*(log(2*4.29, 10))/(1+sin(radians(25)))))
0.34627767629783546
```